# Abstract Iphone/Android Function Call from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

In Iphone, I need to use,

```
 window.location = 'myscheme://FunctionName?Param1=Value1&.........';
```

But In Android,

```
Android.FunctionName(params);
```

This works for me,

```
if(window.Android)
    Android.FunctionName(params);
else
    window.location = 'myscheme://FunctionName?Param1=Value1&.........';
```

But doing this for each and every function is pain for me. Is it possible to abstract these details and use a single function to call both.

Comment: try to create a function with "FunctionName" for iphone and write that statement "window.location = 'myscheme://FunctionName?Param1=Value1&.........';" in that function. i think this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, but don't know whether it good or not,

```
var iphoneUrl = 'myScheme://{0}?{1}'
function callNativeFunction(functionName) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (window.andriod) {
        andriod[functionName].apply(andriod, args);
    }
    else {
        var params = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = args.length; i < len; i++) {
            params += 'param' + (i + 1) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(args[i]) + '&';
        }
        params = params.slice(0, -1);// remove last &
        window.location = iphoneUrl.format(functionName, params);
    }
}
callNativeFunction('functionName', 'param1');
```

Here is String.Format,

```
String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
          ? args[number]
          : match
        ;
    });
};
```